# SSRS Connect line graph lines between series

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, series, linegraph

I have a line chart that tracks the different stages in a process, which currently looks like this:

[image]

Each colour represents a different stage in the life of this process. The graph above shows values only for the pH line:

[image]

The data I'm trying to represent:

[image]

Is there a way to join up these lines so that they aren't disjointed?

Many thanks.

Comment: Please add the data table here. so we can figure it out gap between the line or data point and create other line graph with dot line or something like it.

Comment: Thanks Hiten. I've edited the question to include this info.

Comment: are you using stage column? what i use to do is create line graph on the all the point (Ph Value) with different style of line. then it will look like continue line..

Comment: I think I understand. I've removed the Stage series group and added in an expression to define the colour for each stage. This is now giving me a continuous line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was deceptively easy.

I removed the series groups so that there was no categorisation on the results, and then put in a custom expression on the graph fill which would put a specific colour for each stage. This ensured that there was still a distinction between the different stages, yet the line was not cut up by the categorisation groupings.